# Force string format in Excel cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid

I'm currently exporting to Excel a RadGrid and I have some cells that have the text "1 / 10" meaning that they had 1 hour used for 10 units. When this gets to Excel, it thinks the cell is a date, so it changes the cell to be January-10 which is not what I'm wanting.

I've gone the other direction before (changing a string to a number/date) but I've never had the issue where I needed to make Excel keep the cell as a string and not try to change the format.

How do I do this? I've tried adding a apostrophe to the beginning of the cell text:

```
e.Cell.Text = String.Format("'{0}", e.Cell.Text);
```

but that seems to just make Excel display two apostrophe's at the start of the cell:

[image: Excel example]

---

Update:

I'm using Telerik RadGrid (v2012.2.929.40) and all it does is generate some HTML for Excel to open (you always get that horrible prompt from Excel when trying to open it). So before, if I wanted something to be formatted as a number like I had specific in the grid, I could have the following event that would set the **mso-number-format**. But, this doesn't quite work when I want Excel to display the cell value as strictly text.

```
    protected void RadGridQuote_ExcelExportCellFormatting(object sender, ExcelExportCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cell.Style["mso-number-format"] != null)
        {
            e.Cell.Style["mso-number-format"] = "/@";
            e.Cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio Tools for Office to perform the dump into Excel?

Comment: you want to format the cell not the string. `e.cell.formatnumber = "@"`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Excel Automation in C#, I've found the best results would be to set the `NumberFormat` first, which you should set to "@". Then set the value in your `.Text` property. (If you do it in reverse, it'll convert the date into a number, which you don't want.)

See also [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb213677%28v=office.12%29.aspx) regarding NumberFormat.